# Http request with body

Tags: java, android, json, http-post

i need to create 
POST request url is http://url.com/api/auth/ 
with HTTP-Body authparams={"login”:"login","password":"pasword”}
how can i create it? i try

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://url.com/api/auth/");
        // Building post parameters, key and value pair
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "A@asd.ru"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123"));
        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // writing response to log
            Log.d("myLogs:", response.toString());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.d("myLogs:",EntityUtils.toString(entity) );
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

but i get a bad result

Comment: i get 0, but must get 1.

Comment: You get `0`, *where?*

Comment: a  get the same result if i only load my url

Comment: Log.d("myLogs:",EntityUtils.toString(entity) );
a get token = 0 from server

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your post data into Json format (you can use google library gson or by using org.json).

And then add your json string to the post data
    `nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "A@asd.ru"))`

Comment: can you explain it more?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missunderstanding the piece of code you've posted. This just *sends* a POST request to the server, but currently doesn't process the response from it. To do so, you might use a piece of code like this:

```
InputStream ips;
ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
final BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s;
while (true) {
  s = buf.readLine();
  if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0))
    break;
  sb.append(s);
}

buf.close();
ips.close();
Log.i("Response", "My response is: " + sb.toString());
```

Comment: i think there i get respond 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: You actually do, but you have to **process** it. You might achieve that by the snippet I included (I've updated it, check it)

Comment: My response is: {"token":"0"}
but if my create body with in rigth way it must return token:1

Comment: Doesn't `EntityUtils.toString(entity)` achieve the above functionality??